# How to resolve issue with my Gradle file in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, upgrade

After reinstalling my Android Studio I have big issues because all my projects have problem with Gradle file.

There are .jpeg-s attached
[Gradle File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAFtS.jpg)

[Messages Gradle Sync](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WieK0.jpg)

[Some conflicts in installation area][3]

Comment: Click on "Install Repository and sync project"

Comment: Change compile sdk to 25 and Change your v7 and v4 dependencies to 23.3.0 to 25.0.0 and its done.

Comment: Thanks for answers but I already did it

Comment: did you try to clear and rebuild project after you did what  @AndyDeveloper mentioned (all suggestions?).  and if problem still exist can you copy that error message since i doubt it is still the same issue as it was.

Comment: When I changed sdk and dependencies I just got new messages gradle sync

Comment: After I changed sdk and dependncies i got new message:

Comment: Error:Failed to find target with hash string 'android-25' in: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
Possible cause: Build properties not found for package Android SDK Platform 25
<a href="install.android.platform">Install missing platform(s) and sync project</a>

Comment: but when I click on install is not working

Comment: Hi Miroslave, Error changed.

Comment: go directly to the Tools > SDK and manually install API 25 since you are missing platform to support that API 25.

Comment: I think I already did. I will check one more time.

Comment: after restart AS now i got messages Unsupported Modules.

Comment: Gradle sync failed: Failed to find target with hash string 'android-25' in: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
   Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

Comment: Error message is associated with missing platform and your studio tells you that platform (in this case API 25) is missing. If you installed that platform through SDK properly, issue can also occurs if your Android/SDK location have blank space in path. Try moving SDK and Android to another destination for example (C:\Android\SDK).

Comment: SDK is installed properly, but I don't understand "if your Android/SDK location have blank space in path"? Sorry because I have so many questions. I'm totally confused beginner with this issue.

Comment: There are known issues with Android and SDK installation file paths. So for example if your file is in C:/something/SDK it will work but in case C:/some thing/SDK it will not work. Can you post your gradle file and error one more time to see current configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest fresh new install of everything and keep in mind where exactly will you install it (my suggestion would be to keep it simple like C:\Android\ for studio and C:\Android\SDK for SDK

Also you can click on ***Edit*** next to the SDK location and see what if your SDK report any issues or you can select another SDK location and update missing tools from there.
[image: android SDK]

Or if you would like to tackle current issue on another way, use search and find SDK folder and move it your android folder (don't forget to avoid black space in file path), and again through SDK location don't forget to put new path to the Studio.

After you set up your environment ans run your build gradle again there shouldn't be any more issues like this, or at least when you install missing platforms and tools it will fix thing as it should.

Also have the same dependency version for libraries when you finish setting up environment.

Comment: I will try. Hvala mnogo

Answer (score 1):

Finally done. I resolved uninstalling Android Studio. The real problem was SDK. When you uninstalling AS SDK is still on computer, and I deleted all these files from SDK folder. The best option if you install AS and SDK directly on C:. After that AS working without any problems. Thanks @Miroslav for all your help and patience.

Comment: Important thing is that the problem is solved, you shared that solution and there are also few answers for similar issues which may help someone else in the future. You're welcome :)

Comment: I hope so. I was stuck for few days. Thank you very much one more time.